# Problem with hd video playback (AMD Radeon HD 6320)

Tags: 12.10, drivers, asus, eeepc, proprietary

I have Asus 1225b E-450 with AMD Radeon HD 6320 + Ubuntu 12.10. The problem consist in the video, it is so slow when playing 720p and 1080p. Proprietary drivers are installed. In what could be the problem?

Comment: I had this laptop before. Exact same one, but running 12.04 LTS instead of 12.10. Are you talking about Flash HD 720p/1080p videos?

Comment: Yes. video slow in the browser (Firefox) and video player (VLC).

Comment: I don't remember VLC videos performing that poorly. I know on Windows 8, on IE, (as reference) I could play 1080p YouTube videos without any problems.